# BigQuery Table Column

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I have below json

```
{attribute_values=[{key=PO, values=[234234, 21]}, {key=POReceipt, values=[ABC]}]}
```

> How i will define attribute_values  Column?

currently I defined as String and getting error while inserting via Dataflow

```
"errorMessage": "{\n  \"errors\" : [ {\n    \"debugInfo\" : \"\",\n    \"location\" : \"attribute_values\",\n    \"message\" : \"Array specified for non-repeated field.\",\n    \"reason\" : \"invalid\"\n  } ],\n  \"index\" : 0\n}",
    "stacktrace": null
  }
```

Comment: There's not a lot of info here to help you. Are you able to share your Dataflow/Beam code?

Comment: will this work ?  { "name":"attribute_values", "type":"RECORD", "fields": [ {"name":"key", "type":"String"}, {"name":"values", "type":"Repeat"} ] }

Comment: I have one BQ table that has column attribute_value . I am reading json from PubSu and writing in BQ table . Currently i defined attribute_values as String so my dataflow job fails with error that i mentioned in main problem . Now I need to change Datatype for column attribute_value. I a looking this info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I will define attribute_values Column?

You can create your table as follow:

```
-- create table
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `projectId.datasetId.tableName`
 (   
  attribute_values STRUCT <key String, values ARRAY<STRING>>
 )
```

You can use the below `INSERT` sql example to test how to populate your table

```
INSERT INTO 
    `projectId.datasetId.tableName` (attribute_values)
values (
STRUCT <key String, values ARRAY<STRING>>('PO', ['234234', '21'])
);

INSERT INTO 
    `projectId.datasetId.tableName` (attribute_values)
values (
STRUCT <key String, values ARRAY<STRING>>('POReceipt', ['ABC'])
);
```

[image]

To do this via code you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38105176/1031958) for more details.

Comment: I have one BQ table that has column attribute_value . I am reading json from PubSu and writing in BQ table . Currently  i defined  attribute_values as String so my dataflow job fails with error that i mentioned in main problem . Now I need to change Datatype for column attribute_value. I a looking this info

Comment: @nxverma, Any feedback on this, Hope my answer was helpful. Please consider accepting/voting-up is so.

Answer (score 0):

You have a BQ table with column attribute_value with datatype string and now you want to change the datatype of that column. There are 2 options you can choose from

1. Using a query, selecting all the column in the table then cast the column you want to change then write it to a destination table (although the cast doesn't allow you to cast from string to array/struct [Casting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#casting))
2. Export your data (to GCS) then loading it to a new table

Please check this documentation [Changing a column data type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas#changing_a_columns_data_type) for more details